# jQuery - Modify element with onclick Event

Tags: jquery, onclick, this, element

Here's the "almighty code"!

```js
function testFun(target){
  $(this).addClass("element")
  $(target).addClass("target")
}
```

```html
 
<a href="#" onclick="testFun('.class')" >Element</a>
<div class="class"> </div>
```

Briefly, upon the onClick event I want to modify the element too!
I want to be able to use the same function in multiple situations.
Please provide a solution to be able to do the above mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `this` in your `testFun()` function does not reference the element that called the function - you need to pass in the reference of `this`:

```js
function testFun(element, target) {
  $(element).addClass("element")
  $(target).addClass("target")
}
```

```css
.element {
  color: red;
}
.target {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="testFun(this, '.class')">Target</a>
<div class="class">Target</div>
```

Comment: Is there not a way of using only one parameter?

Comment: Not using an `onclick` attribute, no. If you want to pass the  `this` reference to the event handler function you could instead attach your event with Javascript.

Comment: Your code did the trick, I was only attempting to reach the same thing using only one argument. 
The way you showed me is the way i originally did it.